# Which tense is more correct to use here in this example - Present Perfect Simple/Progressive

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

> I (live) ____ in London since 1994.

Which tense is more correct to use here in this example; A) *Present Perfect Simple* or B) *Present Perfect Continuous*?

> **Answer A):** I have lived in London since 1994.
>   **Answer B):** I have been living in London since 1994.

If have understood right, the meaning of answer A) is that I have lived in London in the past and I might live again in the future, while of question B) is that I have been living there for a specific period of time and I'm still living there.

Please clarify what points I get right and what points I'm missing.

Answer (score 2):

The duration of the situation denoted by the continuous form is not necessarily short,  but it is in some way or other limited. I moved to Prague on a one-year contract many years ago, and stayed on. I noticed after some time that I had stopped saying "I'm living in Prague" and "I've been living in Prague for x years" and started saying "I live in Prague" and "I've lived in Prague for x years". The switch from continuous to non-continuous, not made consciously, reflected my realisation that I had come to see Prague as my permanent home.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these tenses can used **for an action that began at some point in the past and is still continuing** 
 But generally we use the present perfect continuous for actions that started only some time ago.

> Children have been playing for 2 hours.
>
> He has been sleeping since 4 o'clock.

And the present perfect is used for actions that started long ago.

I have lived in London for 3 years.

Comment: Your explanation is very informative. If I would like to use Present Perfect Continuous for an action that started a long time ago, and I would like to focus on the duration of this action, it's correct? For example: I have been living in London for 30 years.

Comment: This is opposite to what I said. If duration is small you should use the present perfect continuous